# Changing controller background from another controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have 3 controllers "Home" "LeftNavigation" "Profile"

Left Navigation is handle via "Revealviewcontroller" lib

Home Controller has a background Image

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_forest.png"]]];
}
```

using LeftNavigation I segue into a modal controller "Profile" . inside the Profile Controller there is IBAction button which I need to trigger to change the background of the "Home" Controller

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: You can use NSNotificationCenter system. It is an observer system which notifies subscribers when registered parameter is changed. Here is a gist you can follow https://gist.github.com/AlanQuatermain/716167

Comment: Notifications, delegate and reference. Either on of these work, yet you haven't tried anything.

Comment: What i tried was inside Profile Controller inside a IBAction I did
- (IBAction)changeTheme:(id)sender {
    
    Home *hm  = [[Home alloc]init];
    [hm.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_2.jpg"]]];
        NSLog(@"Theme changed");
}

Comment: Don't post code in a comment. It's all but impossible to read. As far as the code you posted, why would creating a new instance of the home view controller and setting it's background color change the background color on the existing home view controller? This is like buying a new car and changing the radio station on the new car, then wondering why the radio station on your existing car doesn't change.

Comment: You need a pointer to the existing home view controller, not a new and different home view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things:

You should not try to change another view controller's views directly. Instead, add a property to your home view controller for the background color.

You need some way for the profile view controller to get a pointer to the home view controller. If your home view controller is always around, and the only instance of the home view controller ever created, you could make it a singleton (Search on Objective-C Singleton pattern).

Then in your home view controller's viewWillAppear method, use the background color property to set the content view's background color. That way if the profile view controller changes it, the home view controller update its background color right before it's displayed.

As Lord Zsolt says, you could also use notifications or delegation (Again, search on NSNotificationManager and Objective-C delegate design pattern to learn about those.) To make the delegate pattern work, you would need to set up the home view controller as the profile view controller's delegate.

If you use notifications you'll need a way to pass the desired color to the home view controller. There's a userInfo parameter on notifications that you could use for that.